# How can I use JavaScript to select which object should be scrolling on up / down keys?

Tags: javascript, scroll

In most browsers, when you hover over an object and scroll with mouse, object below mouse pointer will be scrolling. If you click an object and press up and down arrows (or PgUp / PgDn), the object that you clicked last will be the one scrolling.

I want to use JavaScript to select which object will be scrolling on up / down arrows. Obvious solution would be to click() the element with JS, but that does not seem to have any effect on scrolling. I also tried to set objects scrollTop / scrollLeft but this doesn't effect which object will be scrolling next. Any ideas how I can achieve this (basically the same as if user clicked the object)?

I am looking for something like this:

```
<div>
    <div id="redbox">Foo</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div id="greenbox">Bar</div>
</div>

<button onclick="select('redbox');">Scroll redbox from now on</button>
<button onclick="select('greenbox');">Scroll greenbox from now on</button>

<script>
    function select (id) {
        /* Scroll element with 'id' when user presses up / down arrows  next time */
        document.getElementById(id).click() /* doesn't work */
    }
</script>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tv0bpz7r/

*p.s.: I can use JS to keep track of which object should be scrolling and then catch up / down arrow presses and scroll the object I wish to scroll. This works but seems unnecessarily hackish and it also overwrites user's scroll settings since I have to decide how much to scroll.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify these two lines

```
<div class="left container"><div class="long" tabindex="0" id="redbox">Foo</div></div>
<div class="right container"><div class="long" tabindex="0" id="greenbox">Bar</div></div>
```

Added **tabindex="0"** to each one of them

Js

```
function select(id) {
   document.getElementById(id).focus();  
}
```

It will work

Demo : https://jsbin.com/sirunem/25/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Most Welcome !!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(id).focus() /* should work */
```

However, your code is flawed (`ReferenceError: select is not defined`)... I don't yet understand why... :-(

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tested .focus() but it didn't seem to work. Combining it with `tabindex` on element solved the problem (see answer of KrishCdbry)